# The type com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

Upgrading to the last SDK Tools Version (V22) SDK platform tools(V17) SDK Build-tools(V17)I get this msg in Eclipse

```
public class GCMIntentService extends
    GCMFuIntentService{}
```

Important facts- my Project relies on an Android library project which i have created- in this project I have a reference to the gcm.jar(it is in my /libs folder)

any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610296/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-class-not-found-exception-after-upgra/16610384#16610384

Comment: @Raghunandan you must apply step 2 as I stated below the rest is not enough as I found out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this next [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588378/actionbarsherlock-the-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-be-resolved?rq=1) is the  answer

1. Make sure the support library is in the libs folder of the ABS project and nowhere else
2. Right-click on the library --> Build path --> Add to build path
3. Right-click on ABS project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export --> Check the gcm.jar (or any other XXX.jar)file and save
4. Right-click on the project where you have included ABS --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export --> Check the "Android Private Libraries" and save
5. If you have additional projects in your dependency hierarchy, do step 4 for all of this projects
6. Clean the entire workspace (or all affected projects) and hope the best.

Answer (score 1):

The class GCMBaseIntentService is deprecated. Use the [GCM Api instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)

Comment: If you just want to add some information or have good point about deprecated class but you are not answering Q do it in comments below question and not as answer!