# Maven Eclipse Plugin won't add Android support-v4 to build path

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, roboguice

I'm working on a project using RoboGuice with Eclipse ADT, m2e and android-maven-plugin.

I'm using RoboListFragment class which depends on android.support.v4.app.ListFragment, for this reason I've added the following dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Nevertheless eclipse does **not** add that library to build path.
When I build my project from command line everything is ok, but in eclipse I get this error message:

*The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*

The only workaround I found is adding it to the build path as an external jar, but then .classpath refers to my own home directory.

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588378/actionbarsherlock-the-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay I already tried that way without success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

In Maven, this means support-v4 will be in the classpath (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: Removing <scope>provided</scope> works. Thank you! (But I'm not sure it's a clean way)

Comment: `provided` means the application is expecting the container (or other classpath provider) to include that dependency for you.  Thus Maven (and Eclipse) doesn't download it separately.  A typical use for  `provided` scope is for things like Java EE libraries that are provided by Tomcat, WebLogic or other application server.

Comment: Maven downloads provided artifacts. These artifacts will only be used for compilation, and will not be included in the final package, as they are _provided_ by the framework (like Servlet API for Tomcat as you said). @dbellettini if this solved your problem, you should accept the answer. It makes things easier to read.

Comment: Seems like that Eclipse won't see any <scope>provided</scope> dependency whose groupId begins with com.google.android despite Maven builds correctly