# The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

I'm getting an error: **The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced**

```
Session.setActiveSession(session);
if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarSherlock - The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588378/actionbarsherlock-the-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: @ben: I tried all that method but still there is error

Answer (score 2):

After long time i fix this issues,

1.Goto Project->Right click project->Android Tools->Add Support Library.

2. And Goto your Lib project(s)->Right Click->Android Tools->Add Support Library.
3. Finally, Clean all your projects.

Comment: Welcome @ManishaPatel Please put tick mark, It will make confident to other viewers.

Comment: superb +1 save my day

Comment: After "1.Goto Project->Right click project->Android Tools->Add Support Library.", I see this at the end in the Console: "[2017-03-23 11:25:46 - Android Support Jar not found:] C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\v4\android-support-v4.jar". I guess I just have to get android-support-v4.jar and place it in that location.