# extending recyleview but I got both errors :Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar and android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have added recyleview library (unziped .aar and added classes.jar) however when I am creating an adapter and extending it I am having the bellow error

- The type android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChild cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from

The libraries in `Java Build Path` all checked(android 4.4w, android Private Libraries , Android Dependencies)

I added `android-support-v4.jar` in lib folder I got the below error :

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,  but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time  All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
```

The cause of the error maybe because I am usin appcompat_v7.

My question  How to solve the above error and use recycleview ?

Comment: why you adding jars instead of setting compile dependency in gradle file?

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques No I am using eclipse

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am not using gradly ..and I did follow this question but it wasnt helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588378/actionbarsherlock-the-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: I recommend you to use android studio with gradle. This will solve all of your problems and google had announce that they will not support eclipse anymore.

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques I do agree gradle is better but for now I am using eclipse .. so you dont have any idea how to fix that right?

Comment: No, I don't know. Last time I used Eclipse was like a year ago. Why you don't migrate your project to Android Studio now? It's quite easy.